# How can I send OpenCV output to browser with python django?

Tags: python, django

I want to send an OpenCV output to a browser(web application) that I'm working on. I know how to make a frame appear using my webcam controlled by OpenCV but I want to integrate that frame inside my website. What can I do in order to integrate in my website? Here's the code for OpenCV and thank you in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pickle

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Cascades/data/haarcascade_eye.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read("trainer.yml")

labels = {"person_name": 1}
with open("labels.pickle", 'rb') as f:
orig_lables = pickle.load(f)
lables = {v:k for k,v in orig_lables.items()}

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    #capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, 
minNeighbors=5)
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
   # print(x, y, w, h)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    id_, confidence = recognizer.predict(roi_gray)
    if confidence >= 45 and confidence <= 85:
        print(id_)
        #print(lables[id_])
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX = 0
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        color = (255, 255, 255)
        name = lables[id_]
        stroke = 2
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (x,y), font, 1, color, stroke, cv2.LINE_AA)

    img_item = "captured-image.png"
    cv2.imwrite(img_item, roi_gray)

    color = (0, 255, 255) #bgr format
    stroke = 2
    width = x + w
    height = y + h
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (width, height), color, stroke)
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for(ex,ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex,ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)


#display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('APS recognition', frame)
if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

#when everything is done, release the caputure
cap.release()
cap.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will require some external plumbing but it can be done in two steps:

- Stream your OpenCV output, you can use VLC, FFMPEG or others (see [Sending OpenCV output to VLC stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579542/sending-opencv-output-to-vlc-stream))
- Add the stream to your web page (see third answer here [Streaming via RTSP or RTP in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735933/streaming-via-rtsp-or-rtp-in-html5))