# Streaming Video from raspberry pi camera

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

How do i stream live video from my raspberry pi to my phone on vlc?
I am aware of tools such as raspivid, but that only gives streams the raw output of the camera, I want to process the frames using opencv, add a few text boxes, and facial recognition, etc...

EDIT: I think i was unclear about what i wanted.
I want to capture video from a camera to a raspberry pi, process it, add boxes, from YOLO/PyTesseract, etc, and stream all those processed frames in real time to my phone's VLC client

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can do this using opencv.

```
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam)
   test, frame = cap.read()
```

**process the frame**

I didnt really written the whole code but i am confidently it works if you do this. I assume you webcam is connected to PC or another raspberry pi.

1. Capture the image (referring to code above), write and established socket connection and send the image over to raspberry pi.
2. At your raspberry pi receive the image from socket connection, do whatever processing you need and send through VLC stream. You may refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579542/sending-opencv-output-to-vlc-stream)
3. Your phone can access the image using http:ip:port

Comment: I think i was unclear with the question... I've edited it, can you please look at it again?