# Stream a color map to RTSP and kvssink

Tags: gstreamer, vlc, rtsp

My goal is to stream a color map to rtsp and from there to stream it to kvs.
By color map I mean that I've created a numpy matrix, `32x24x3`, that I write to the screen at around 7 fps, as shown here:
[Sending OpenCV output to VLC stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579542/sending-opencv-output-to-vlc-stream)
and convert it to an `RTSP` stream.
My line is:

```
python3 rtsp.py | vlc -I dummy --demux=rawvideo --rawvid-fps=7 --rawvid-width=32 --rawvid-height=24 --rawvid-chroma=RV24 - --sout "#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=200,fps=7,width=32,height=24,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8557/color.sdp}"
```

This works and if I open the vlc GUI I can read it and see the frames.
My next goal is to stream it to kvs using `gstreamer`.
Usually I stream h264 source to kvssink and it looks like that (from amazon's tutorial):

```
 gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://127.0.0.1:8557/color.sdp"  ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264, format=avc,alignment=au ! kvssink stream-name="colorStream" storage-size=512
```

But it seems that the gstreamer can't read the frames and I get:

```
INFO - freeKinesisVideoStream(): Freeing Kinesis Video stream.
DEBUG - curlApiCallbacksShutdownActiveRequests(): pActiveRequests hashtable is empty
```

I've tried all kinds of codecs but nothing works.
Does anybody maybe have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's documentation is either outdated or only works for some system configurations. I had the same issue and had to use a different gstreamer incantation. For you it would look like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://127.0.0.1:8557/color.sdp"  ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! kvssink stream-name="colorStream" storage-size=512
```

Note the `h264parse` in place of `video/x-h264, format=avc,alignment=au`. I spent hours figuring this one out and the lightbulb in my head went off after using the debug [guide](http://www.ideasonboard.org/blog/20160805-gst-debugging.html) to precisely jack up the debug level of the part of the pipeline dropping frames, and then reading this issue [thread](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/issues/193#issuecomment-474093882)  on the KVS producer sdk repo.

I'm not a gstreamer expert and can't explain *why* this works, or why this [plugin](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videoparsersbad/h264parse.html?gi-language=c) is considered "bad", but I hope this helps others stranded in the same problem.